# Mailing Account record details from Custom Button

Tags: workflow

I want to create a "Send Account Details" Custom button on the standard Account detail page. When I click the button, it should send an email to the specified record owner with all the Account record's details. This email should be based on a Visualforce template so I can determine formatting. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this? Maybe with a workflow?

Comment: If you are using a custom button, a workflow wouldn't make sense.  Just have the custom button do it.  You can make javascript execute or navigate to another page to fill your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a workflow. Like Yann suggested just now, you can use the button to update a field which triggers the workflow you created.

You can't use a VisualForce page to format the outgoing, but you can use a custom email template. Have a look here for more information about sending emails with custom templates from workflows:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_alerts.htm

Comment: need to do using vf page

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this : your button execute an update of the account, updating a technical Date/Time field.

Just add a workflow fired by the update of this field.